# FPGA Will pausing entities (by pausing their clock input) reduce the overall power consumption?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I'm currently creating a multiple entity project where all of the entities have clock synchronous architecture (no behaviourals) and most of the entities work on derived clocks.
I'm using DE0 Nano, so my source clock is 50MHz and I have 4 derived clocks: 1 MHz, 500 kHz, 10 Hz and 1 Hz.

Disclamer: While I am aware that doing things this way is much less power-efficient, I've been wondering if there is something I could do to remedy this at least a little (I'm open to ideas).

Now, in the top-level entity I have an "event handler", which can decide which entities should work at any given moment.
Therefore I came up with an idea to wire an on/off clock switch for the derived clock input signals to the lower level entities and disable some of them (the clock inputs) when I don't need a given entity to work for a while (as I understand, this should stop their processes from firing for that time).

Since I don't have an easy way to test that idea (I estimate it will take a moderate amount of work and time, especially setting up the power consumption measurement) I wanted to ask whether anyone tried something similar and/or knows if it's worth a shot?

For your information, currently when the entities are in "sleep" mode, their processes fire on each rising clock edge, check an internal state or flag variable/signal and stop e.g.:

```
process (1MHz clock) is
    variable ...
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        if state = ready and enable = '1' then
             ...
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

Or maybe there an other, better way to do it?

Comment: The code you show does not 'pause' the clock. It only prevents state progression. Of course stopping state progression can save some dynamic switching power consumption, but it will be fractional. There is the possibility of ["clock gating"](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/white_papers/wp370_Intelligent_Clock_Gating.pdf), which actually blocks the clock from reaching the registers. Still, FPGA's are very power-hungry components. In the background there the clock distribution network will still be running, consuming power. Plus other static power consumption.

Comment: Yes, I only included the code to show how much is currently processed when a component is stalled and effectively how much would could be cut off when I disable the clock.
And indeed "clock gating" is what I had in mind, I just couldn't describe it better. So what you're saying is, that it could help a bit but possibly it's not worth the time it will take to implement?

Comment: Your derived clocks have really low frequencies. The dynamic power consumption of those clock domains will very low, so stopping their clocks by clock gating will not save much.  Most people would not bother gating those clocks, unless you are running on batteries.

Comment: If power consumption is an issue, I would consider not using FPGA's... It's really funny that for instance Xilinx is constantly patting themselves on the back for designing powers efficient FPGA's. Like they show [here](https://www.xilinx.com/products/technology/power.html), the new generation has 2x performance/Watt. What they don't show is that the new generation has 2x more resources, so the total power consumption is probably equal. It is difficult to find actual numbers on their site. wp488 seems to indicate that depending on the junction temperature, the static power can be up to 0.5W